# leaflet 2 layers with different resolutions

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, scale, proj, resolution

EDIT : Wrong projection pastet into this post.

Im trying to add 2 layers to the same leaflet map that have different resolutions.

They got the same Projection and bounds but different resolution.

I have both of the working fine when running seperatly.

The 2 different pro4 is:

```
var layer1Proj = = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:25832', '+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs',
    {
        resolutions: [132.29193125051253, 66.14596562525627, 33.07298281262813, 16.933367200065604, 8.466683600032802, 4.233341800016401, 2.6458386250102506, 2.1166709000082005, 1.0583354500041002, 0.5291677250020501, 0.26458386250102506, 0.1984378968757688, 0.13229193125051253, 0.06614596562525626, 0.03307298281262813]
        , bounds: L.bounds([442000.000000, 6250000.000000], [637000.000000, 6410000.000000])
        , origin: [442000.0, 6410000.0]
    }

);

var layer2Proj =  = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:25832', '+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs',
    {
        resolutions: [6553.6, 3276.8, 1638.4, 819.2, 409.6, 204.8, 102.4, 51.2, 25.6, 12.8, 6.4, 3.2, 1.6, 0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.025, 0.0125]
        , bounds: L.bounds([442000.000000, 6250000.000000], [637000.000000, 6410000.000000])
        , origin: [442000.0, 6410000.0]
    });
```

Is the any whay i can get both layers on the same leaflet map?

Regards,
Jacob

Comment: they don't have the same projection.

Comment: Sorry wrong projection pstet into this post, now its the right one.

Comment: Anybody have tryed something like this?